# How to find shift value for all keyboard characters and symbols?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, keyboard

What is the easiest way to get the "uppercase" value of all keys and symbols on a keyboard using Python?

I am aware that this works for standard letters

```
mystr = "a"
print(mystr.upper()) # "A"
```

But what if I want to convert "1" into "!"? What is the best way to do this? `mystr.upper()` in this case outputs "1" still.

Comment: The upper case for `1` is not `!` - that's just a feature of your keyboard, not a language rule

Comment: [Map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) symbols to their *shift* values.

Comment: @rdas not to get bitter but that's why in the title it says "shift value" and I put the "uppercase" in quotes in my question lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this from purely Python.  The physical characteristics of the keyboard are embedded in the keyboard's circuitry, not anywhere you can programmatically inquire about that mapping.  You would need to implement a way for each client to specify the attached device, or allow you to probe the system, to find the model specs.  *Then* would you need to look up and download the mapping from the manufacturer specs.

Also, what mandates that your input characters are coming from a keyboard?  There are many possible input streams.

Comment: Thanks for a sane answer, helps out a lot. I am working within a keyboard press/release framwork at the moment. Perhaps I can look into other input streams. Thanks!

Comment: You're quite welcome.  If you want simulations -- or even a data stream -- check out `generators` and `Popen`; I've used these to encapsulate all of the streams I need to handle for both work and play.

Answer (score -2):

A keyboard in London will probably look different from one in Paris.
For *your* keyboard, you want to write down a mapping:

```
shifted = {
    '1': '!',
    '2': '@',
    ...
}

mystr = '1'
assert shifted[mystr] == '!'
```

Comment: So how would an application handle different keyboards? Say they accept a username and password with special characters and want this to work across different keyboards. What is the most acceptable way to handle if someone presses SHIFT+3 we get "#" on my keyboard and the corresponding symbol for a different keyboard?

Comment: Stop it, asking an XY question will get you nowhere (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You asked what is the easiest way to obtain certain values on _a_ keyboard, using python, and now you have an answer to that question. Create a new post in which you describe what you're _really_ interested in, and perhaps someone will be able to answer _that_ question. If security is your true interest, it is important to explicitly disclose that.